# CSS images only inside one div

Tags: css, image, html, nested

[www.angelodias.com.br/blog](http://www.angelodias.com.br/blog)

My blog has a featured image inside a slider and several images through the post. To solve a problem (images on post bigger than column) I did this:

```
img {
max-width:450px;
height:auto;
}
```

The problem is: this code also changes my slideshow max-width to 450px, and that's not good. Is there a way for the CSS to work ONLY inside the post's text?

Example:

```
<div class="slideshow"> slideshow without custom IMG css, only template css </div>
<div class="entry-content"> post content with custom IMG css and template css</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to post more information than this.  Maybe a link to the site or our code for the slideshow.

Comment: I am sure you can target the img more specifically then targeting all images on the page

Answer (score 0):

You can try targeting the images use the entry-content container

```
.entry-content img {
    // ....
}
```

If you use img tag, it will target all images on the page, where .entry-content img will only target the images inside of entry-content elements and that's where your images are and slide show are not.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress allows to add max-width to images, simply go to Settings -> Media
or you can just select the images inside of your content, this should work:

```
.entry-content img {
      max-width: 450px; 
      height: auto;
}
```